# Gluon-eclipse stuck at a very old version (like 1.0)

Tags: javafx, gluon

I just recently installed the gluon-eclipse plugin so I could make javafx based android apps, but whenever I tried to run the apks it generated I kept getting a black screen. I think I'm using a very old edition and don't know where to get the update, I searched gluon on the eclipse marketplace abd it gave me 1.0 again. I also tried the search for updates thing and that didnt work either.

Any help is appreciated

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.zach.apcs.APCSHelper'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @JoséPereda posted

Comment: Indeed, that's really old. You should check for updates, or uninstall the Gluon plugin, and install it again from here:  https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gluon-plugin